# knockout.js update optionstext after getting data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm looking for a way to update a select element's optionsText after I've received my data from an ajax call.

I've got what I think is a fairly standard view setup of a select element with multiple associated fields and check-boxes.

Before I do an ajax call to get the data I use the optionsText property to set a "Loading data..." option and once the data call is done I want to delete the optionsText and set the select option to the first "real" one in the list, aka the first element in the array returned from my data call.

If not delete the optionsText, I want to at least change it to "Pick a foobar" so the user knows the data call is done.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the values of the options model as done here

```
var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.selected=ko.observable();
    self.options=ko.observable([{txt:'Loading',val:-1}]);
    self.status=ko.observable('Loading');
    self.init=function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
             self.status('Loaded');
            self.options([
                {txt:'First Option',val:0},{txt:'2nd Option',val:1}]);
        },1000);
    }
    self.init();
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/SRLvj/